# What tables do i need to create a database for a cellphones?

Tags: sql, vb.net, relational-database, database-schema

Creating a database for a project and well i sort of understand the concept of database but i don't know where to start. I know for my database i need to have the following:
Brand of the phone, model, some feature like size, operating system and touch screen?
To make this more like a database i decided to add more information such as carrier. So am thinking to make a database i would need these tables:

Mobile: ID phone(Primary key), Brand, Model

Phone: Model, size, and touch screen availability

Carrier: service provider, phone Id

The question is would this be a efficient database or should i combine the mobile and phone table? If this isnt good then what's the best way to make an collection system of cellphones?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track.
I would even say to break up the brand and model into 2 different tables.
To learn more about this relationship read this article
[Database Relationships](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)

### MobileDevice

IDDevice, IDBrand, IDModel, IDCarrier

### MobileBrand

IDBrand, BrandName

### MobileModel

IDModel, IDBrand, ModelName, Size, TouchScreenAvailability

### Carrier

IDCarrier, serviceprovider

Answer (score 1):

Steps of creating a database for new application

1. Identify all functional entity
2. Create separate tables for each of them
   **Note:** While creating it please follow normalization rules
3. Once functional entity related table creation is done than based on there relationship create corresponding tables to represent relationship
4. After that create your application related transacional tables
5. For any of sensitive type of transaction create tracking/history table(s)
6. For all lookup/referring related object create corresponding lookup tables

**Note:** While creating database for an application please consider few points like

1. scalablity of that application
2. scope of that application
3. target users, there location, type of user

***Hope it make sense to you in order to start creating database for your application***